# What is the deck and name of this card that gives extra food?

Tags: agricola

I remember seeing a card once, but I cannot remember which deck it belongs to, or whether it was a minor improvement or occupation. I am also having trouble finding it on google. The text was similar to:

"When you use a minor or major improvement to convert building resources into food, you receive two extra food"

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a website that lists out all of the cards and effects [here](https://alavigne.net/Gaming/Agricola/agricola-comp-v9.0.html).

The card you are asking about is the Artisan:

> At most once per harvest, when you use an improvement to convert a building resource to food, you receive 2 additional food.

You can search through that list for things like "2 additional food" to find similar cards.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the web link!